# MySQLdump with WINDOWS10 : OS errno 13 - (Permission denied) when executing 'SELECT INTO OUTFILE'

Tags: mysql, select, into-outfile, select-into-outfile

I am unable to write tab separated text files into specified TSV/ folder using mysqldump on WINDOWS10 (MySQL80 service).

- The Command prompt (or powershell) is in admin mode.
- `secure-file-priv =""` in `my.ini` MySQL config file.
- MySQL was installed on my local computer and I use a localhost connection with the `root` username.

Command is:
`mysqldump -T C:\Users\...\20200430_Dump\TSV\ --user root  -p database_name`

OUTPUT:

> mysqldump: Got error: 1: Can't create/write to file 'C:\Users...\20200430_Dump\TSV\table_name.txt' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied) when executing 'SELECT INTO OUTFILE'.

They are many related post on LINUX but I am **specifically** looking for an solution for **WINDOWS**

My small hypothesis:
Some linux posts suggest that mysqld use a specific user-account (that seems to be `mysql` in linux but this is unfortunately not documented at all for any OS). So I imagine that when the server is executing `INTO OUTFILE` queries he needs to have permission for the TSV/ folder, but i do not know how to do give him this permission in WINDOWS.

best

Comment: If you give universal write access to the folder in question, does that fix the problem?

Comment: Universal write access ?. System, my_personal_user account and Administrators (Laptop_name\Administrators) have already full control over TSV/ folder

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Left click on your TSV/ folder >  Properties  > Security Tab > Edit > Add

You need to add NETWORK SERVICE in `Group or User names` with `Full control` privilege (probably just Write is sufficient).

[image]

The `mysqldump` now works (tested on windows10)

Answer (score 4):

[image: Mysql dump screen]

You need to create an empty SQL file and specify the path to it.

Comment: @Rohit Gupta thanks for editing